# BackStackEntryCount and FragmentManager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, kotlin

I have searched a lot and found many explanation over internet but my confusion is still there about `Fragments` and `FragmentManager` and `findFragmentByTag`

Suppose I have three fragments `FragmentA,FragmentB,FragmentC` and **A,B,C** are their tags respectively.

I executed `FragmentTransaction` in sequence like this:

1- Add FragmentA {BackStackEntryCount=1, BackStack=[A]}

2- Add FragmentB {BackStackEntryCount=2, BackStack=[B,A]}

3- Add FragmentA {BackStackEntryCount=3, BackStack=[A,B,A]}

4- Add FragmentC {BackStackEntryCount=4, BackStack=[C,A,B,A]}

5- Replace FragmentA {BackStackEntryCount=5, BackStack=[A]}

After step 5, it shows that `replace` will remove(destroy) all existing `fragments` from `BackStack` and will add new one but `BackStackEntryCount` showing that It remembered/saved 5 Transactions. So, I have `FragmentA` on Top and showing to user. Problem is that if now I execute:

```
supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("A") // returns null But it should return FragmentA? But why it is returning null?
supportFragmentManager.fragments // shows that FragmentA in returned List
```

My perception is that `BackStackEntryCount` remembered only total transactions saved by `addToBackStack("SOME_TAG" or null)` but it doesn't update it when `replace` removes all fragments from `FragmentManager`. Please help me clear my understandings.

Comment: Please post your code for doing this.

Comment: Code? I'm talking about understandings. Not any error in my code

Answer (score 0):

The documentation on the method `findFragmentByTag`

> Finds a fragment that was identified by the given tag either when inflated from XML or as supplied when added in a transaction.

```
supportFragmentManager
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.container, fragment, "TAG")
    .addToBackStack("StackFrameName")
    .commit()
```

The tag is set in `replace` or `add` methods or in XML.

`addToBackStack` takes a name for the stackframe that you can use to look up stack frames but not fragments themselves.

`replace` swaps the fragment in the given id for the one provided
`add` add's the fragment to the view.

The big difference to these methods `add` adds its views to the container whereas `replace` replaces the views in the container with its own views.
The don't affect the backstack unless backstack code is added to the transaction.

Update:

Once you replace a fragment or remove a fragment it is no longer attached to the fragment manager to be able to find by tag but if it has been added to the back stack you can reattach it to the fragment manager by pop the backstack until it comes back. Which is what the `StackFrameName` is for.

Comment: As you can see in my steps 1,2,3,4,5. Im adding them to backStack.

Comment: Yes but `findFragmentByTag` doesn't look at the backstack name but at the `add`ad and `replace` tags. You use the backstack name for `popBackStack(String name, int flags)` but not for finding a particular fragment.

Comment: fragments belong by far to the worst designs ever. I have never seen so many questions and bugs than with fragments.